# Solution to Integral Equation obtained by modifying Newsvendor Model

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integral-equations

I have the following equation and want to find p(q)

$$
a p(q)+b-2 c \int_{0}^{q} p(x) d x=0
$$

I tried to differentiate, but do not know how to proceed with this integral equation. Please help.
Here a,b and c are constants. p(0)=0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may differentiate the given equation

$ap(q) + b - 2c \displaystyle \int_0^q p(x) \; dx  = 0 \tag 1$

with respect to $q$, and obtain

$ap'(q) - 2c p(q) = 0; \tag 2$

taking

$q = 0 \tag 3$

we obtain from (1)

$ap(0) + b = 0, \tag 4$

or

$p(0) = -\dfrac{b}{a}, \tag 5$

which we take as the initial condition for the ordinary differential equation (2); the well-known solution is then

$p(q) = p(0)e^{2cq/a} = -\dfrac{b}{a} e^{2cq/a}. \tag 6$

***Note Added in Edit, Friday 16 October 2020 7:03 PM PST:*** First, a few remarks in response to the comments of our OP Conorlash, which may be found appended to this answer.  Having followed the links he/she provided, I am forced to admit that my understanding of the economic/financial applications of this model is still severely limited, so I am afraid I cannot offer any useful interpretive insights at the present time.  Meanwhile, we may continue to investigate (1) from a purely mathematical point of view.  To this ende we note that if our OP's suggested initial condition

$p(0) = 0 \tag 7$

is adopted, then for any $q$ we have, in light of (6),

$p(q) = p(0)e^{2cq/a} = -0 \cdot  \dfrac{b}{a} e^{2cq/a} = 0, \tag 8$

assuming of course

$a \ne 0, \tag 9$

as is evident from (5), which indicates that

$b = 0 \tag{10}$

is equivalent to (7) under the condition (9).

Finally, it should be observed that assigning different values to the coefficients $a$, $b$ and $c$ will have consequences in terms of the solution space; the engaged reader my discover these through further simple analyses of the cases of (1). ***End of Note.***

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Here p(x) is a cumulative distribution function which gives optimal profit for the Newsvendor problem. How do I interpret the solution?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newsvendor_model.

Comment: @Conorlash:  not sure how to interpret the answer, being unfamiliar with this problem.. I'll check you link.  If I think of anything, I'll let you know.  Cheers!

Comment: In this I took the salvage price as a variable and tried to find the p(q) which maximises profit.

Comment: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=4Msm6AboCQM

Comment: @Conorlash:  I must bid your patience.  I *will* think more about this, but it is not the only thing on my plate right now.  Will get back to you when I have something.  Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for replying. I just wanted to clarify.

Comment: Thanks for the "acceptance".  Still working on you questions.

Comment: @Conorlash:  yes I realized that and will address the issue when I finish my write-up.

Comment: Did you get something?

Comment: @Conorlash:  I have a couple of ideas but I'm tied up with work right now I'll try to add something to my answer tonight.  Sorry about the delay.  Cheers!

Comment: Are you free right now?

Comment: I have one doubt the answer which we initially got satisfies the equation as well.

Comment: @Conorlash:  can you be a little more explicit?

Comment: According to the model the b= selling price- cost price and is greater than zero.

Comment: Here q is the optimal value at which the profit is maximum.

Comment: @Conorlash:  well, as I said, I haven't really been able to address the economic interpretation.  I just took the math problem as stated.  Cheers!